# filter a table by combination of selected cell values using VBA - syntax error

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

Can you please help me with the code below, i keep getting a **syntax error**

The objective of the macro is filter by multiple rows selection under same column.

The lines i am getting a syntax error on are:

```
sColumn(n) = sColumn(n) & _
If(sColumn(n) vbNullString, ",", "") & oCell.Text


If sColumn(n) vbNullString Then
```

The full code is below:

```
Sub combinationFilter()

Dim oRange As Range
Dim oArea As Range
Dim oCell As Range
Dim oLO As ListObject
Dim sColumn() As Variant
Dim n As Long

' Create Filter
Set oLO = Selection.ListObject

If Not oLO Is Nothing Then

    ReDim sColumn(1 To oLO.ListColumns.Count)

    Set oRange = Intersect(Selection, oLO.DataBodyRange)

    For Each oArea In oRange.Areas
        For Each oCell In oArea.Cells
            n = oCell.Column - oLO.Range.Column + 1
            sColumn(n) = sColumn(n) & _
            IIf(sColumn(n) vbNullString, ",", "") & oCell.Text
        Next oCell
    Next oArea

    ' Apply Filter
    For n = LBound(sColumn) To UBound(sColumn)
        If sColumn(n) like vbNullString Then
            oLO.Range.AutoFilter _
            Field:=n, _
            Criteria1:=Split(sColumn(n), ","), _
            Operator:=xlFilterValues
        End If
    Next n

End If

End Sub
```

I am also getting a mismatch error on the below lines:

```
If sColumn(n) like vbNullString Then
oLO.Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=n, _
Criteria1:=Split(sColumn(n), ","), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could you edit to make your code readable with proper syntax indentation?

Comment: @SamGilbert - I think the `<>` (not `=`) got swallowed up by markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an [IIF function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264412.aspx), not an IF.

```
sColumn(n) = sColumn(n) & _
  IIF(CBool(Len(sColumn(n))), ",", vbNullString) & oCell.Text
```

Additionally, your sColumn array may be null/vbnullstring/empty string. You only want to attempt the [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) if there is something in sColumn(n), not if there isn't.

```
' Apply Filter
For n = LBound(sColumn) To UBound(sColumn)
    If sColumn(n) <> vbNullString Then
        oLO.Range.AutoFilter _
        Field:=n, _
        Criteria1:=Split(sColumn(n), ","), _
        Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End If
Next n
```

You cannot split an empty array element (e.g. vbNullString) into anything so you are getting the Error 13: Type mismatch.

Comment: thanks for the above.  i am getting an mismatch error on the below:    oLO.Range.AutoFilter _
Field:=n, _
Criteria1:=Split(sColumn(n), ","), _
Operator:=xlFilterValues

Comment: The remaining code in your question is malformed. Are you using `If sColumns(n) <> vbNullString Then` ? It is impossible to tell.

Comment: apologies thats "=" ... If sColumns(n) = vbNullString Then

Comment: It shouldn't be. I'm talkin about where it is used around the .AutoFilter. You should only continue to try and autofilter is if **is not** a vbnullstring.

Answer (score 2):

Pertinent to your case, the correct syntax could be like the following:

```
sColumn(n) = sColumn(n) & IIf(IsNull(sColumn(n)), "", ",") & oCell.Text
```

or, as pointed out by member @Jeeped, using `Like` operator instead of `Is` (or using equal sign `"="`):

```
sColumn(n) = sColumn(n) & IIf(sColumn(n) Like vbNullString, "", ",") & oCell.Text
```

Hope this may help.

Comment: i am trying to look into it. i am still having the same error

Comment: Please refer to my extended answer. Best regards,